how to close and open a new browser session in playwright
I would like to close and open a new browser session in playwright or at least clear cookies and cache.
So far, this is my best attempt:
//close and reopen a fresh browser
await browser.close();
const browser2 = await playwright.chromium.launch();
const page2 = await browser2.newPage();
await browser2.newContext();
await browser2.newPage();

I welcome any feedback, if this is possible.

update:
Here is information for the use case, if desired. I would like to combine the following 2 tests into one test. Currently I use only 1 worker to keep the tests running in the proper order.
test('take fullpage screenshot baseline image', async ({ setUp, page }) => {
    await page.screenshot({ path: `tests\\baseline-snapshots\\${pageName}.png`, fullPage: true});

});


test('assert fullpage screenshot comparison', async ({ setUp, page }) => {
    await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot(`${pageName}.png`, {fullPage: true });
        
});

It would be nice to combine them into one test so that I can run tests  in parallel. I am comparing a before and after version of a webpage screenshot, so I would like to have a clean experience when the page loads, with the cache cleared.

I would ask- what is your use case? What are you trying to achieve by this?

I need the cache cleared because I am doing a screenshot comparison, a before and after version of a webpage. I can separate them into 2 tests, if needed, but I want to run the tests in parallel, with the tests running in order.

@JohnP2 Why not use the browser and page parameters provided to you by the test blocks? One generally doesn't need to manage browsers and pages by hand in Playwright tests. I don't see any screenshotting happening here, so the use case could use more clarity and concrete code.

@ggorlen added above. I think the way I am doing it is the best that can be done

I would rather clear the cookies if that will help
await context.clearCookies();

